# Permutation & Probability

Tags: probability, self-study, combinatorics

There are total of 10 persons in a queue. If two particular people out of the 10 persons are to be together, what is the probability of that happening?
Do I group the 2 people together and then insert them into the remaining 8 persons??
Thanks

Comment: That strategy should work if you do it right.

Comment: One way to interpret @Glen_b's comment is to consider the chance that $k$ particular people in a queue of length $n\ge k$ are together.  There are $n-k+1$ possibilities for the location of the first person in that group and there are $\binom{n}{k}$ possible distinct groups. The answer therefore is $$(n-k+1)/\binom{n}{k}=\frac{k!(n-k+1)!}{n!}=(n+1)/\binom{n+1}{k}.$$ For $n=10, k=2$ that is $11/55$.

Comment: @whuber +1 yes, that was what lay behind my response. At the time I was trying to get the OP to suggest an answer based on his or her strategy (given it is self-study), but since the question has been answered, I think it makes sense to give the details of the strategy, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there were no restrictions, the number of permutations of $10$ people would be $10!$.

If two particular people are to be together, we can consider these two people as one group. The people in this group can be arranged in $2! = 2$ ways.

Furthermore, there are $8$ people left. Hence, we have a total number of $(8 + 1)! = 9!$ permutations since we consider the particular two people as one group.

Taken together, there are $2! \cdot 9!$ ways to arrange the people such that two particular ones are togehther. Therefore, the probability of this event is $\dfrac{2! \cdot 9!}{10!} = \dfrac{2}{10} = \dfrac{1}{5}$.